# Present a view controller as a dialog modal

Tags: ios

I have a view controller with its views specified in a storyboard.

The view is a simple table view which I believe can be stretched or shrinked without any issue.

In the code, when I want to load my view controller, I simply do

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc"];
[self showViewController:vc sender:self];
```

Now, is there a way so that I can present my view controller like a dialog?

I would like my the view inside that view controller to show up as if it was a dialog, say, with 20 px margin all around, the margin should be transparent.

Thanks

Comment: "is there something that I can do without more than 20 lines of code." – what's the reason for this restriction? Anyways, you could write the entire application on one line if you'd want to, lines of code aren't the best metric for anything.

Comment: I have removed that line.

Comment: Since you have a storyboard, why not use a show segue?  Select "over current context" and set the size of the view

Comment: @Paulw11 I need to pass some specific parameters to my vc when I click on a button or something. Is that also something that can be configured with a segue?

Comment: Of course. You use `prepareFoSegue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the addSubView function.

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc"];
CGRect frameVc = vc.view.frame;
[vc.view setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, frameVc.size.width - 40, frameVc.size.height - 40)];

[self.view addSubview:vc.view];
```

Anyways I recommend you that create a custom view

Comment: Do you set the Storyboard ID of your ViewController in Main.storyboard?

Comment: Yes I did. It only throws "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" when I do [self.view addSubView:vc.view]; When I do [self showViewController:vc] it works fine. I think I'll have to go with a custom view then. I just thought it is very easy to show a view controller view as a dialog.

Comment: the VC does have a value. vc.view is not nil. [vc.view description] says it is a UITableView etc.

Comment: Thats weird! so, does the crash happens in the line: [self.view addSubview:vc.view] ? If you want try to show us your code

Comment: Actually that is the exact code I am doing... I do have some category added to the UIViewController that will be pushed (DGActivityIndicatorView for pull to refresh). Maybe that changed something..? Anyway thanks a lot for your help. I am sure your method is correct judging on other google results. I will accept your answer.

Comment: Maybe the crash happens in vc controller, try to add a empty viewController

Comment: You are right. Empty VC works. Must be something going on in my vc that is preventing the view from being added.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's easy. From your first view controller, instantiate an instance of the second one and add it as a child view controller. Then just add the view from the child view controller as a subview. Whatever transparent areas of your subview will allow the first view controller to show through.

Comment: Is your answer basically what @DiegoQ is doing?

Comment: Yes, but I'd also suggest adding the new view controller as a child view controller. See "func addChildViewController(_ childController: UIViewController)" That way you keep a reference to the view controller to help prevent crashing. And I wouldn't set the frame inset that way, I would just design the new view's constraints appropriately, that way rotation will work.